# How to scrape and concate text in <br> tags with Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to scrape parts of this site:

https://www.booklooker.de/B%C3%BCcher/Bastian-Sick+Der-Dativ-ist-dem-Genitiv-sein-Tod-Ein-Wegweiser-durch-den-Irrgarten-der-deutschen/id/A02ArCkS01ZZy

More accurate this part:
[image]

The html looks like this:
[image]

I tried this, but it doesn`t work:

```
   from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
    import requests
    page = requests.get("https://www.booklooker.de/Bücher/Bastian-Sick+Der-Dativ-ist-dem-Genitiv-sein-Tod-Ein-Wegweiser-durch-den-Irrgarten-der-deutschen/id/A02ArCkS01ZZy")
    
souped = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
description = souped.find(class_="propertyItem_13").find_all("br").text
```

But that doesn`t work. Do you have any idea, how it is possible to scrape all the text?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: The `<br>` tag *never* has text content, it's a self-closing (= empty) tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just use the `separator` argument of `get_text`

```py
print(souped.find(class_="propertyItem_13").get_text('\n').strip())
```

you'll get

```
Beschreibung:


Zustand siehe Bild. Zusätzlich: Ecken und Kanten leicht bestoßen. Seiten und Buchschnitt altersbedingt leicht verfärbt. Buchschnitt fleckig, siehe Bilder. Ab der Hälfte des Buches sind die Seiten oben leicht gebogen.
 
 
Die deutsche Sprache kennt zwar nur vier Fälle, dafür aber über tausend Zweifelsfälle. Heißt es Pizzas oder Pizzen? Gewinkt oder gewunken? Wann schreibt man Storys und wann Stories? Hat der Genitiv noch eine Chance — trotz des Dativs und dem Dativ zum Trotz?
 
Dieses Buch präsentiert die großartige SPIEGEL¬ONLINE-Kolumne »Zwiebelfisch«, die Woche für Woche Leser amüsiert, schockiert, belehrt und begeistert.
 
»Man spürt das Vergnügen, das der Umgang mit gutem Deutsch bereitet.« FAZ
 
»Wo der Duden nicht weiter weiß, weiß Sick Rat.« Saarbrücker Zeitung
 
Über das Buch:
 
Die oder das Nutella — diese Frage hat schon viele Gemüter am Frühstückstisch bewegt. Der, die, das — wieso, weshalb, warum? Ob Nutella nun weiblich oder sächlich ist, ist sicherlich keine Frage auf Leben und Tod, aber eine Antwort hätten wir schon gern. Wir? Ja, wir hilflos Verlorenen im Labyrinth der deutschen Sprache. Wir, die wir unsere liebe Not mit der deutschen Sprache haben. Und leichter, verständlicher oder zumindest nachvollziehbarer ist es nach der Rechtschreibreform auch nicht geworden.
In seinen hinreißend komischen und immer klugen Kolumnen bringt Bastian Sick Licht ins Dunkel der deutschen Sprachregelungen und sortiert den Sprachmüll. Ist der inflationären Verwendung von Binde-strichen noch Einhalt zu gebieten, angesichts von Spar-Plänen und Quoten-Druck? Versinken wir sprachlich gesehen nicht längst im Hagel der Apostrophe, wenn Känguru's plötzlich in den Weiten Australien's leben? Derlei Unsinn scheint nicht mehr aufhaltbar, wenn es nicht dieses Buch gäbe. Darauf zwei Espressis!
 
Der Autor:
 
Bastian Sick, Jahrgang 1965, Studium der Geschichtswissenschaft und Romanistik, Tätigkeit als Lektor und Übersetzer; von 1995-1998 Dokumentationsjournalist beim SPIEGEL-Verlag, ab Januar 1999 Mitarbeiter der Redaktion von SPIEGEL ONLINE. Seit Mai 2003 dort Autor der Kolumne »Zwiebelfisch«.
```

---

But if you want to target the `<br>`s specifically, you can copy [this function](https://gist.github.com/Driftr95/8b799ab0c235dab90c69f875c99a9f81) into your code and use it like

```py
print(html_to_text(souped.find(class_="propertyItem_13"))[1])
```

and that will give you

```
Beschreibung:Zustand siehe Bild. Zusätzlich: Ecken und Kanten leicht bestoßen. Seiten und Buchschnitt altersbedingt leicht verfärbt. Buchschnitt fleckig, siehe Bilder. Ab der Hälfte des Buches sind die Seiten oben leicht gebogen.


Die deutsche Sprache kennt zwar nur vier Fälle, dafür aber über tausend Zweifelsfälle. Heißt es Pizzas oder Pizzen? Gewinkt oder gewunken? Wann schreibt man Storys und wann Stories? Hat der Genitiv noch eine Chance — trotz des Dativs und dem Dativ zum Trotz?

Dieses Buch präsentiert die großartige SPIEGEL¬ONLINE-Kolumne »Zwiebelfisch«, die Woche für Woche Leser amüsiert, schockiert, belehrt und begeistert.

»Man spürt das Vergnügen, das der Umgang mit gutem Deutsch bereitet.« FAZ

»Wo der Duden nicht weiter weiß, weiß Sick Rat.« Saarbrücker Zeitung

Über das Buch:

Die oder das Nutella — diese Frage hat schon viele Gemüter am Frühstückstisch bewegt. Der, die, das — wieso, weshalb, warum? Ob Nutella nun weiblich oder sächlich ist, ist sicherlich keine Frage auf Leben und Tod, aber eine Antwort hätten wir schon gern. Wir? Ja, wir hilflos Verlorenen im Labyrinth der deutschen Sprache. Wir, die wir unsere liebe Not mit der deutschen Sprache haben. Und leichter, verständlicher oder zumindest nachvollziehbarer ist es nach der Rechtschreibreform auch nicht geworden.
In seinen hinreißend komischen und immer klugen Kolumnen bringt Bastian Sick Licht ins Dunkel der deutschen Sprachregelungen und sortiert den Sprachmüll. Ist der inflationären Verwendung von Binde-strichen noch Einhalt zu gebieten, angesichts von Spar-Plänen und Quoten-Druck? Versinken wir sprachlich gesehen nicht längst im Hagel der Apostrophe, wenn Känguru's plötzlich in den Weiten Australien's leben? Derlei Unsinn scheint nicht mehr aufhaltbar, wenn es nicht dieses Buch gäbe. Darauf zwei Espressis!

Der Autor:

Bastian Sick, Jahrgang 1965, Studium der Geschichtswissenschaft und Romanistik, Tätigkeit als Lektor und Übersetzer; von 1995-1998 Dokumentationsjournalist beim SPIEGEL-Verlag, ab Januar 1999 Mitarbeiter der Redaktion von SPIEGEL ONLINE. Seit Mai 2003 dort Autor der Kolumne »Zwiebelfisch«.
```

---

In this case , the difference is barely noticeable, but if you had more tags, you'd definitely notice that the first method spaces out *everything*, not just `br`; but if this is all you need it for, then the first method is much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

You can just invoke the `get_text()` method to grab the entire description

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page = requests.get("https://www.booklooker.de/Bücher/Bastian-Sick+Der-Dativ-ist-dem-Genitiv-sein-Tod-Ein-Wegweiser-durch-den-Irrgarten-der-deutschen/id/A02ArCkS01ZZy")
    
souped = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
description = souped.find(class_="propertyItem_13").get_text(strip=True)

print(description)
```

**Output:**

```
Beschreibung:Zustand siehe Bild. Zusätzlich: Ecken und Kanten leicht bestoßen. Seiten und Buchschnitt altersbedingt 
leicht verfärbt. Buchschnitt fleckig, siehe Bilder. Ab der Hälfte des Buches sind die Seiten oben leicht gebogen.Die deutsche Sprache kennt zwar nur vier Fälle, dafür aber über tausend Zweifelsfälle. Heißt es Pizzas oder Pizzen? Gewinkt oder gewunken? Wann schreibt man Storys und wann Stories? Hat der Genitiv noch eine Chance — trotz des Dativs und dem Dativ zum Trotz?Dieses Buch präsentiert die großartige SPIEGEL¬ONLINE-Kolumne »Zwiebelfisch«, die Woche für Woche Leser amüsiert, schockiert, belehrt und begeistert.»Man spürt das Vergnügen, das der Umgang mit gutem Deutsch bereitet.« FAZ»Wo der Duden nicht weiter weiß, weiß Sick Rat.« Saarbrücker ZeitungÜber das Buch:Die oder das Nutella 
— diese Frage hat schon viele Gemüter am Frühstückstisch bewegt. Der, die, das — wieso, weshalb, warum? Ob Nutella nun weiblich oder sächlich ist, ist sicherlich keine Frage auf Leben und Tod, aber eine Antwort hätten wir schon gern. Wir? Ja, wir hilflos Verlorenen im Labyrinth der deutschen Sprache. Wir, die wir unsere liebe Not mit der deutschen Sprache haben. Und leichter, verständlicher oder zumindest nachvollziehbarer ist es nach der Rechtschreibreform auch nicht geworden.In seinen hinreißend komischen und immer klugen Kolumnen bringt Bastian Sick Licht ins Dunkel der 
deutschen Sprachregelungen und sortiert den Sprachmüll. Ist der inflationären Verwendung von Binde-strichen noch Einhalt zu gebieten, angesichts von Spar-Plänen und Quoten-Druck? Versinken wir sprachlich gesehen nicht längst im Hagel der Apostrophe, wenn Känguru's plötzlich in den Weiten Australien's leben? Derlei Unsinn scheint nicht mehr aufhaltbar, wenn es nicht dieses Buch gäbe. Darauf zwei Espressis!Der Autor:Bastian Sick, Jahrgang 1965, Studium der Geschichtswissenschaft und Romanistik, Tätigkeit als Lektor und Übersetzer; von 1995-1998 Dokumentationsjournalist beim SPIEGEL-Verlag, ab Januar 1999 Mitarbeiter der Redaktion von SPIEGEL ONLINE. Seit Mai 2003 dort Autor der Kolumne »Zwiebelfisch«.
```

Answer (score 0):

The text isn't in a `<br>` tag. You need to get text from `PropertyValue`

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't return any results, because the `<br>` does not contain any tags. In fact, the tag does not support ending tags and can only be closed at opening: `<br/>`. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br

You might want to use the `get_text` method: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text